# How to use for loop in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, for-loop, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with 4 times the same instructions, only the file name changes:

```
COPY ./MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj /app/MyProject.Common/
RUN dotnet restore /app/MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj

COPY ./MyProject.Manual/MyProject.Manual.csproj /app/MyProject.Manual/
RUN dotnet restore /app/MyProject.Manual/MyProject.Manual.csproj

COPY ./MyProject.Widgets/MyProject.Widgets.csproj /app/MyProject.Widgets/
RUN dotnet restore /app/MyProject.Widgets/MyProject.Widgets.csproj

COPY ./${CLIENT_PROJECT}/${CLIENT_PROJECT}.csproj /app/${CLIENT_PROJECT}/
RUN dotnet restore /app/${CLIENT_PROJECT}/${CLIENT_PROJECT}.csproj
```

Is it possible to use a for loop, to have `COPY` and `RUN` only once ? something like:

```
FOR [MyProject.Common, MyProject.Manual, ${CLIENT_PROJECT}]
  COPY ./${FOR_PARAM}/${FOR_PARAM}.csproj /app/${FOR_PARAM}/
  RUN dotnet restore /app/${FOR_PARAM}/${FOR_PARAM}.csproj
ENDFOR
```

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `FOR/LOOP` instructions in docker file, so I suggest you to:

1. Provide a single `COPY` instruction which copies all the files arranged into distinct subfolders.
2. Write and `COPY` a shell script which loops through subfolder compiling them.
3. Provide a single `RUN` instruction for the above script.

Regards.